# Unable to Install shinyapps package

Tags: r, shiny

Trying Steps as explained [in the getting started guide](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html).

Installing from RStudio on a Ubuntu 14.04 Machine.

Getting the following Timeout Error:

> devtools::install_github('rstudio/shinyapps')
>   Downloading github repo rstudio/shinyapps@master
>   Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
>   Timeout was reached

Have tried cloning a github repo from terminal and was able to do it, so doesn't look like a network problem.

Comment: I just installed shinyapps from RStudio on ubuntu 14.04 by running exactly the command you posted. The installation worked, I can't reproduce your error. I'm using `devtools` version1.8.0.

Comment: Can you access [shiny apps repository](https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps/) using web browser? If so, you can simply download [a zipped repository](https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps/archive/master.zip), unpack it, and install using `devtolls::install('path/to/unpacked/archive')`.